# dynamically create listbox with expander control in wpf through MVVM

Tags: wpf

I want to dynamically create multiple list boxes with expander control in wpf through MVVM and prism. Can anybody suggest me how to implement this

Please find the below format

Program details(This is Expander control and below items should populate in listbox)
HBO
AXN

Episode details(This is Expander control and below items should populate in listbox)
Part 1 
Part 2
Part 2

Schedule details(This is Expander control and below items should populate in listbox)
Morning
Afternoon
Evening

It can keep on adding new items as similar as above.

Please suggest me how to achieve this or send me the sample code.....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it is Hierarchical data. You can create control template on tree view and each tree view item will have listbox inside expander.